# Using ARRAYFORMULA with Multiple cell values in to one

Tags: google-sheets

Im trying to add few cell values to one separate (Column) Cell with Line brake for each Cell Value.
(Using Google Sheets)
The Formula im Using is

```
={"ID" ;ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE(H2:H,CHAR(10),I2:I,CHAR(10),J2:J,CHAR(10),K2:K,CHAR(10),L2:L,CHAR(10),M2:M))}
```

The Issue im facing is all the data is coming on to Cell O2
Please check Image
[image: Issue im facing]

What I want is for each row to get the values on relevant Column

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The Sheet Gets Updated with New Rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can also try in O1

```
={"ID"; ArrayFormula(substitute(transpose(substitute(trim(query(transpose(substitute(H2:M, " ", "_")),,rows(H2:H))), " ", char(10))), "_"," "))}
```

[image]

Comment: Im Trying to Get a Cell Value (SheetA) which was created by a ARRAYFORMULA to a separate Sheet (Sheet B). Where I need to Make Changes to it on new Sheet ( SheetB )

The Data is on Column P Cell 2 on Sheet A and data Rows are Added 

What Must i Use to get relevant data But it must be editable 
Tried IMPORTRANGE But It gives errors

Comment: Values imported with a formula can't be edited or the formula will brieak. Only alternative would be to import these values with a google script.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need this in cell `O1`:

`=ARRAYFORMULA({"ID" ;H2:H&CHAR(10)&I2:I&CHAR(10)&J2:J&CHAR(10)&K2:K&CHAR(10)&L2:L&CHAR(10)&M2:M})`

Probably good to add a `trim` as well:

`=ARRAYFORMULA({"ID" ;trim(H2:H&CHAR(10)&I2:I&CHAR(10)&J2:J&CHAR(10)&K2:K&CHAR(10)&L2:L&CHAR(10)&M2:M)})`

Comment: Thanks Im Not an expert.. This did the job verywell

Comment: It's probably useful to add `trim` as per the update.